# How do you use Sencha ExtWebComponents in an ASP.NET Razor page project?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, extjs, razor-pages

I want to be able to use buttons and other UI elements from Sencha ExtWebcomponents in a Razor page application. For example, I would like `Index.cshtml` to look something like

```
@using WebMatrix.Data;

@{
Layout = "../Shared/Index.cshtml";
}

<script>
    Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
        fullscreen: true,
        padding: 10,
        items: {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: text,
            handler: handler
        }
    });
</script>
```

I've tried bundling some of the JS files (see below) in a template ExtWebcomponents app that I thought seemed important, but I'm still getting errors like `"SCRIPT5009: 'require' is not defined"` or `"SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'define' of undefined or null reference."`

```
var scriptBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/extwc_scripts/ExtWCBundle");
scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/extwc_scripts/extract-code.js");
scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/extwc_scripts/build/ext/ext.js");
```

and then in the master layout I would put

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/extwc_scripts/ExtWCBundle")
```

Could you please advise me on the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

That's not actually *Razor Pages*. It's the old [ASP.NET Web Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/getting-started) framework. If you have a choice and are learning, I would recommend [Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com) over Web Pages, which hasn't been developed for about 7 years, now.

Whether Web Pages or Razor Pages, the issue you have is likely the same. When you include scripts in a specific page, you should do so in an `@section` name "scripts". That way, it will be included in the layout page AFTER library scripts, which should be included before the `RenderSection("scripts")` call in the layout page:

```
@using WebMatrix.Data;

@{
Layout = "../Shared/Index.cshtml";
}

@section scripts{
<script>
    Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
        fullscreen: true,
        padding: 10,
        items: {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: text,
            handler: handler
        }
    });
</script>
}
```